# Get in the meaning of the past in the sense, but for some reason it is written in the present

Tags: grammar

I came across this sentence:"i feel blessed everyday that *i get to be married to my best friend*".
I can't figure out what time *Get* should be here ,isn't that in the past? is it because she has already performed this action, or is there something I don't understand? thanks

Comment: The title should be in the form of a question. Just saying.

Comment: _Get to be married_ is not the same thing as _get married_. The idiom _get to_ means 'be allowed to'.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thank you ! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's all in the present.

*I am married to my best friend* means I'm still married to him/her and plan to continue to be married to him/her for some time, possibly for the rest of our lives.

*I get to be married to my best friend* means I am (lucky enough; strangely enough; or whatever) married to my best friend.

"I get to" means, essentially, "I've somehow managed" or "I'm allowed to."

As in:

> "Would you like to accompany me to the concert?"
>
> "Sure, provided I get to listen to the music, too, and not just your
> gossip."

Comment: So in this sentence, can I replace *get* with *manage to*?It's just that so far, when studying English, I have not shouted such a sentence(I did not see ,unfortunately, that you can do such a replacement).And in translators there is usually a bunch of *got married*

Comment: "Got married" is a horse of an entirely different color. Entirely! You'll recall the movie "Argmageddon." The psychologist asks a physicist why he works on rigs - two PhD's and all. Wouldn't he rather work in a lab? To which the answer is, among other things - "Because I get to blow shit up." In this case, "get to" means "I'm allowed to." So, you see, "get to," can mean "I'm allowed to," "I'm fortunate enough to" or "I have a chance to."

Comment: Now it's clearer.thank you very much! :)

Comment: @Вячеслав: My pleasure.